# How can I use html video tag on safari (odoo 11)?

Tags: html, video, safari

I've checked a lot of post on the same argument, but I didn't find a solution.

My html code is the following (it is an Odoo 11 web page):

```
<video playsinline="true" autoplay="true" muted="true" loop="true" 
    class="bckgroundMyVideo" poster="/web/image/5016" preload="auto">
    <source src="/web/image/5644" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="/web/image/5658" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

it is working on chrome/firefox/edge, but not on Ipad or Iphone, I've tryed a lot of combination, but as of now I'm not able to let it work on safari.

Update: the video is not working on IPad neither with Safari or Chrome...

Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: It's weird, because the tag video is supported on safari, it's not working only on your ipad or on every ios?

Comment: @Lafa it is not working in both the Ipad I have for testing purpose (Ipad Pro, Ipad mini), but it is working on other browser and also on mobile (android/chrome)

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @JamesCoyle on safari it is shown the poster image. 
if I try to access the video directly from the navigation bar with the complete url to the file, it show for a second the player loading, than the play button strikethrough.

Comment: i'm not sure, but maybe you need to add an extension to the files in the source tag: src="/web/image/5644.mp4" type="video/mp4"

Comment: @Lafa Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried, and it didn't work.